# Opengl - GLfloat not being recognized

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Having some trouble with this class declaration, Im trying to create nodes for an openGL implementation of Dijktra's shortest path algorithm. the getX(), getY(), getZ() methods cause an error:

error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getX’ with no type

Im compiling with g++ on ubuntu linux. Command: g++ -lglut -lGLU -lGL projecttest.c

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#define kWindowWidth 800
#define kWindowHeight 600 
#define NUM_NODES 3

using namespace std;

class Node {
    private: 
        GLfloat x, y, z;
        int numLinks;
        Node *links[];
    public: 
        Node(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, ...);
        ~Node();
        GLfloat getX();
        GLfloat getY();
        GLfloat getZ() {return 0.0f;}
} Node;

Node nodes_g[NUM_NODES];
```

I think the problem is in the preprocessor macros. Im new to openGL and somewhat new to c++ so any advice is good, but what I really want to know is why im getting the error.

Comment: Why are you including both `<cstdio>` and `<iostream>`?  (This doesn't have anything to do with your problem; I'm just curious.)

Answer (score 8):

You need

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

before including headers for OpenGL extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Then you should not need GL/gl.h or GL/glu.h, although you may have to put cstdlib *before* GL/glut.h